# How to get a specific attribute an object in JSON?

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jax-rs

I working with JAX-RS and I want to get a JSON Object from my resource.

For example, I have the next code:

Book class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Book {

    private int id;

    private String name;

}
```

And person class:

```
@XmlRootElement
private class Person {

    private int id;

    @XmlElement(name="full_name")
    private String fullName;

    @XmlElement(name="book_id")
    private Book book;

}
```

I want get this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "full_name": "Gustavo Pacheco",
    "book_id": 8
}
```

And don't get this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "full_name": "Gustavo Pacheco",
    "book": {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Cien Años De Soledad"
    }
}
```

How can I get only id attribute from book class for get a more simple JSON?

Comment: You're receiving that structure because book is an Object of type Book within Person's class. If your requirement is that simple why you just add bookId as an attribute of class Person instead of creating a whole Book instance?

Comment: I understand your point but I have a book instance because that object represents a JPA OneToOne relationship.

Comment: It is usually not a good idea to expose your internal objects. I suggest creating a separate interface

Comment: I agree with pedrofb. You would be better to create a series of objects specific to the web service endpoints you're exposing, and map your internal objects into those external representations. That way you can make your external representations look exactly like you need to, without changing the internals of your application.

Comment: So, the best solution is to create, for example, a person class for data access and a person class for REST web services resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing for these cases is to have the classes corresponding to the DTOs and entities corresponding to the database model independently.

For example:

```
package com.github.ryctabo.example.entity;

/* Entity class */
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {}

package com.github.ryctabo.example.dto;

/* Data Transfer Object class */
@XmlRootElement
public class PersonData {}
```

This ensures the integrity of the database model, and independently you have how you are going to display the data in a different class.